# Mail sent , But not receiving in mail inbox

Tags: php, sendmail

```
<?php
$to="emailid@domain.com";
$subject="A subject";
$message="this is a message for u AAAAAA";
$from="myemailid@domain.com";
$header="from:".$from;
if($mailInfo=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header)){
echo $mailInfo;
echo "\n mail sent";
}
else{echo "mail not sent";}
?>

//Output   1
//         mail sent
```

The output of `$mailInfo` is producing `1` and it is also echoing "mail sent"
But I cannot receive email in my inbox and spam as well ..

Comment: Are you sending the mail from home? Some mailservers just don't accept a mail from a private Mailserver.

Comment: Is it on a localhost or online? If using, e.g., XAMPP, it sends it as a 'File' that it stores in C:\windows\temp, c:\xampp\tmp, or C:\user\name\appdata\local\temp. Alternatively, if not in Windows, /var/log/mail?

Comment: I am using localhost wamp server . I download sendmail from www.glob.com.au/sendmail/ and config sendmail.ini and php.ini according to tutorials .

Answer (score 2):

Mail servers nowadays have to work very, very hard to filter out spam. They tend to look unfavourably on obviously hand-crafted emails with barebones SMTP headers, like yours.

Although you say you've checked your "spam" box, this mechanism often works at a lower-level than that, simply rejecting the email outright at any of the SMTP servers *en route*, long before it hits your account and Bayesian/content-based filtering. This also has no effect on the return value of `mail`, which simply acknowledges the mail has been sent to the local spooler.

I would recommend using a fully-fledged SMTP library (such as *PHPMailer*) which knows all the right headers to use to "look like" a proper email.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to use a email library like `PHPMailer` and send your emails via a real SMTP server.

There may be problem with mail configuration. If you use PHPMailer, It will handle all the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Check the mail in the spam.

In Many cases the mail reaches there if the domain server is not trusted from the mail server.
So you need either use the mail library or to use the **SMTP configuration**.

Comment: Thanks this helped me, and Lightness's points are also very helpful. I have been struggling with a similar issue and spotted a few of my test messages in my spam folder.

Comment: P.S. I marked up this reply as the clear heading was noticeable by my weary eyes.